# Vertical transformation of DEM from EPSG:3035 to EPSG:4326

Tags: python, gdal, dem, gdalwarp, vertical-transformation

I am trying to convert a DEM file from EPSG:3035 (ETRS89-extended / LAEA Europe) to EPSG:4326 (WGS 84) with `gdalwarp`. EPSG:3035 uses the European Terrestrial Reference System 1989 ensemble datum where as EPSG:4326 uses World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble datum.

*I assume that as the datums are different there should be some height difference in the DEM after conversion.*

As per my search, it can be done with `gdalwarp` with proj string ([link1](https://spatialthoughts.com/2019/10/26/convert-between-orthometric-and-ellipsoidal-elevations-using-gdal/), [link2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/191565/vertical-datum-conversion-of-a-raster-with-gdal?noredirect=1&lq=1))

`gdalwarp` documentation also states that,

> Starting with GDAL 2.2, if the SRS has an explicit vertical datum that
> points to a PROJ.4 geoidgrids, and the input dataset is a single band
> dataset, a vertical correction will be applied to the values of the
> dataset.

Here there is a mention of geogrid (egm96_15.gtx for EGM96 elevation as described in [this link](https://spatialthoughts.com/2019/10/26/convert-between-orthometric-and-ellipsoidal-elevations-using-gdal/)).

```
gdalwarp  -s_srs "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_def" -t_srs "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +geoidgrids=egm96_15.gtx" cartosat.tif cartosat_orthometric.tif
```

**But I couldn't find the gtx file that should be used for EPSG:3035**.

So, I have done the transformation as follows

```
gdalwarp -s_srs "+proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs" -t_srs "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +type=crs" input.tif output.tif
```

I have used [PROJ.4 string of EPSG:3035](https://epsg.io/3035-to-4326) in `-s_srs` and [PROJ.4 string of EPSG:4326](https://epsg.io/4326) in `-t_srs`.

With this, the output.tif does show some difference in height (around 1.7m in some area while none in other).

**Is my approach to vertical transformation correct, or I am missing something here?**

Edit-1:
Even if I don't use proj.4 string and do the reprojection as follows, I am getting the same output as with the proj.4 string.

```
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 input.tif output.tif
```

Comment: @Kasper but this egm96_15.gtx file can't be used for ETRS 89, right? This gtx file is for geoid (EGM based) whereas the ETRS 89 is ellipsoid-based.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked your question. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/261440/converting-elevation-from-eu-dem-etrs89-to-wgs84 for reference. II guess it also mainly depends what you want as an output. If input data is altitude above sea level (based on a given reference), do you really need the output altitude to be relative to the WGS84 spheroid ?